# Angularjs - Hiding table rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a toggle button in a table row, once clicked, I'd like to leave the last clicked row visible, while hiding all other rows of the table.

This is done using two flags: 'showAll' (global) and 'showGridRow'- per row.

A row is displayed if one of the flags is true:
ng-show="{{showAll}}||product.showGridRow"

code:

```js
$scope.showAll = showAll;

$scope.toggleReadings = function toggleReadings(product) {
  if (product.showGridRow == undefined) {
    //if undefined, this is first click - set to false so it will be enabled immediatelly
    product.showGridRow = false;
  }

  product.showGridRow = !product.showGridRow;
  //if true, hide all others, else show all
  showAll = !product.showGridRow;

};
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product ID</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Topic</th>
      <th>Active</th>
      <th>Readings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>                      
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products" ng-show="{{showAll}}||product.showGridRow">
      <td>{{product.productId}}</td>
      <td>{{product.productName}}</td>
      <td>{{product.topic}}</td>
      <td>{{product.Active}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="..." ng-click="toggleReadings(product)" >
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**My Question:**

This works only when placing a breakpoint at the beginning of the toggleReadings() function and debugging the code. While running the code "normally" nothing happens.
What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a great time to use the built-in [`filter` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Comment: this isn't going to work as you expect.  `ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each row, causing scope inheritance issues with the `$scope.showAll` primitive.  the `toggleReadings(product)` function will, in effect, create a new `$scope.showAll` property for each row the first time the button is clicked, and will not affect the parent property, nor any of the properties created so far within each row other than itself.

Comment: this *could* be fixed by using an object instead of a primitive, but as @ryanyuyu mentioned, a filter makes more sense here than `ng-show` anyway.

Comment: I don't think a filter fits here conceptually, as whether the element is shown depends on the state of other elements/the state of the parent scope. I'm sure you could get a filter to work, but this seems like a perfectly fine use-case for `ng-show`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/o5aofze1/

```
$scope.showAll = true;
$scope.products = [{
  productId: 2,
  productName: 'asd',
  topic: '123',
  Active: 'true'
}, {
  productId: 3,
  productName: 'asdada',
  topic: '213123',
  Active: 'false'
}]

$scope.toggleReadings = function toggleReadings(product) {
  if ($scope.productToShow == product) {
    $scope.productToShow = undefined;
  } else {
    $scope.productToShow = product;
  }

  $scope.showAll = !$scope.productToShow;

};
```

With the filter being: `ng-show="showAll||productToShow == product"`

Answer (score 0):

This worked using filters:
"ng-repeat="... | limitto:selectedRow:rowsToDisplay" 
while the button click sends row index.
Thanks all!